# Why are FFT numbers so high?

Tags: fft

My input numbers are close to 10, here is a sample of some:

```
9.259992,9.253408,9.322236,9.375503,9.406026,9.507771,9.509567,9.403034,9.397048,9.36054,9.265977,9.262985,9.216302,9.228272,9.338395,9.430565
```

I am using this PHP library
[thinkingmik/FastFourierTransformation](https://github.com/thinkingmik/FastFourierTransform)

My peak numbers in response are about 500. A control which was done using another tool is 1-1.5

FFT is well over my head, so I am trying to read this library to get a bit of an idea, but can't figure this out. The interesting thing is the client says the chart seems to be correct, just numerical values are wrong.

Comment: Have you looked at the formula for the DFT? (The FFT is an algorithm that computes the DFT efficiently...so I would start with that and the answer should be very clear to you). And for your client just divide the answer by N where N is the length of the FFT and things should be as you expect.  This is equivalent to averaging without doing the final divide. Same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by Dan Boschen in a comment, these number aren't really surprising. Usually the DFT is defined as

$$X[k]=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x[n]e^{-j2\pi kn/N}\tag{1}$$

where $x[n]$ is the input sequence and $N$ is the DFT length. So bin zero, i.e., $X[0]$, is just the average value of your input sequence multiplied by the DFT length. The maximum value of $|X[k]|$ can be as large as the maximum value of $|x[n]|$ multiplied by the DFT length.

Comment: You are right, I guess Dan Boschen had the right answer, but he marked as a comment, so I could not mark it as accepted. I thank you both for the details and support. Thanks @danboschen and matt-l